# How to get fragment reference from ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-pageradapter

I am trying to get the reference to a specific Fragment called `MyChatsFragment` after instantiating it with a custom `SectionPageAdapter`.

First, I am adding the Fragments

```
    mSectionsPageAdapter.addFragment(new CatalogFragment());
    mSectionsPageAdapter.addFragment(new MyBooksfragment());
    mSectionsPageAdapter.addFragment(new MyChatsFragment());
    viewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPageAdapter);
```

Then I am trying to retrieve `MyChatsFragment` this way:

```
 MyChatsFragment myChatsFragment = (MyChatsFragment) mSectionsPageAdapter
                                                                 .getRegisteredFragment(2);
```

Yet, `getRegisteredFragment(2)` returns `null` and while debugging I have noticed the following:

In the Adapter, `instantiateItem` is only being called twice, therefore adding `CatalogFragment` and `MyBooksFragment` to `registeredFragments` SparseArray. This would explain why `getRegisteredFragment(2)` returns `null`. But why `MyChatsFragment` is actually created and the app is perfectly functional if `instantiateItem` is not even called for it?

**Why isn't `MyChatsFragment` being added to `registeredFragments` SparseArray while other fragments are?**

Is `getItem(position)` a viable solution?

After checking [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15261142/7201671), I have adapted my `SectionsPageAdapter` by overriding `instantiateItem` and `destroyItem` as you will be able to check the below code:

```
public class SectionsPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{
private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
private final SparseArray<Fragment> registeredFragments = new SparseArray<Fragment>();

public void addFragment(Fragment fragment)
{
    mFragmentList.add(fragment);
}


public SectionsPageAdapter(FragmentManager FM)
{
    super(FM);
}
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
   return mFragmentList.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mFragmentList.size();
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    Fragment fragment = (Fragment) super.instantiateItem(container, position);
    registeredFragments.put(position, fragment);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    registeredFragments.remove(position);
    super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
}

public Fragment getRegisteredFragment(int position) {
    return registeredFragments.get(position);
    }
}
```

Note: If needed, I can share `MyChatsFragment` code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `viewPager.getAdapter.getItem(position);` from your `Activity` or parent `Fragment`.

**Description (Modified)** - As you wrote `addFragment()` adds a fragment to `mFragmentList` and  you are adding fragment by this method too by calling:

```
mSectionsPageAdapter.addFragment(new MyChatsFragment())
```

And `getItem()` returns a fragment from `mFragmentList` where you added your fragment. So if you want  to get `MyChatsFragment` reference just use:

```
MyChatsFragment myChatsFragment = (MyChatsFragment) 
mSectionsPageAdapter .getItem(position);
```

*or*

```
MyChatsFragment myChatsFragment = (MyChatsFragment) 
viewPager.getAdapter.getItem(position);
```

Comment: As I asked in my post, please provide a brief explanation regarding `getItem` method.

Comment: As you wrote `addFragment()` adds a fragment to `mFragmentList` and  you are adding fragment by this method too by calling `mSectionsPageAdapter.addFragment(new MyChatsFragment())`. 
 and `getItem()` returns a fragment from `mFragmentList` where you added your fragment. So if you want  to get `MyChatsFragment` reference just use `MyChatsFragment myChatsFragment = (MyChatsFragment) mSectionsPageAdapter .getItem(2);`  or `MyChatsFragment myChatsFragment = (MyChatsFragment) 
 viewPager.getAdapter.getItem(2);`